# Copy and update data Sharepoint Deisgner 2013

Tags: list, workflow, data

I would like to copy data from 6 lists (same column names) and paste them into one list with 5 additional columns. Copied data should also be updated according to changes in those 6 lists in the future (changes in already existing rows or newly added ones). Alterations in the new list should not influence the base 6 files and data entered into the new list should not be erased during the list update. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about creating a new list and copying all the data but a similar functionality exists OOTB. You can create a linked data source which would gather data from all the 6 lists and display that in a data view web part. This way, any update in the other lists will also reflect in the data view web part. See: http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2013/06/14/creating-a-linked-data-source-in-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried this, but it is not exactly what I wanted to achieve. It creates a view of all of my lists, however I can't add new columns which also could be modified.
Workflow that copies data between the lists works perfectly, but I can't update data using it.